# Complete urls in Tweepy when expanded_url is not enough (integration with urllib2?)

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2, tweepy

I have recently started to use Tweepy, in particular the api.user_timeline. My script downloads a series of tweets from users and prints to a text file most of the various details available in the Tweepy Status call. My problem is with reversing the tiny urls from twitter. I have read in an answer on this site that the correct way to address it would be to use the 'expanded_url' command within Twitter entities and that is what I did. Here is my code:

```
import tweepy
import codecs


auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler("xxx", "xxx")
auth.set_access_token("yyy", "yyy")

with codecs.open("file.txt", encoding='utf-8', mode='w+') as f:
   api = tweepy.API(auth)
   for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, "xxx", include_entities=True).items():
    ...
    # Extracting info from the entities
       for hashtag in status.entities['hashtags']:
           f.write(format(hashtag['text']))


       for url in status.entities['urls']:
           f.write(format(url['expanded_url']))
```

The problem is that these expanded urls are not always the full urls that I need. For example, the code in question for a tweet gave me as a result 'http://goo.gl/sOH17n' which still hides the true website the article is from. I have a snippet of code that gives me the complete url with urllib2 but when I put the two of them together, I get a **'HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden'**. Here's my trial that DOES NOT WORK (it's always integrated with the part before, so it's not a problem of not going through authentication)

```
import urllib2
for url in status.entities['urls']:
        expanded_url=url['expanded_url']
        fullurl= urllib2.urlopen(expanded_url)
        f.write(format(fullurl.url))
```

So, my question is, is there a way to find the TRULY complete urls within Tweepy? If not, why wouldn't the integration with urllib2 work? I apologize if the question seems trivial but I can't seem to find my way out of this one and tweepy's documentation is sketchy.

Thanks in advance for any answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to swstephe, I focused on the head request, so as to avoid opening the page and I found the module requests that works quite nicely.

So here is the solution I found:

```
   import requests
   for url in status.entities['urls']:
        expanded_url=url['expanded_url']
        r= requests.head(expanded_url)
        if r.status_code in range (200,300):
            f.write(format(r.url))
        elif r.status_code in range (300,400):
            f.write(format(r.headers['location']))
        else:
            f.write(format(r.status_code))
```

I still don't understand why urllib2 wouldn't work. Guess that I'll use requests from now on. Thanks for the help. It was truly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The URL comes from Google, so I don't think Tweepy is storing where Google would direct you if you clicked on the link.  You can find that out using httplib, (so you can get HEAD, without a full fetch of the page it would load):

```
import httplib
from urlparse import urlparse

url = urlparse('http://goo.gl/sOH17n')    # split URL into components
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(url.hostname, url.port)
conn.request('HEAD', url.path)            # just look at the headers
rsp = conn.getresponse()
if rsp.status in (301,401):               # resource moved (permanent|temporary)
    print rsp.getheader('location')
else:
    print url
conn.close()
```

When I run it, I get a URL, not a 403 error.  That error usually indicates you don't have permission to view that page, so I guess the URL you gave isn't the one you posted.

Comment: Thanks! The url I posted is exactly the one I was given, so therein lies my problem. The solution you suggested avoids the Forbidden problem but it doesn't work consistently, as in it only unscraps some of the tiny urls. So it's even more puzzling. Why wouldn't it work with urllib2 that instead takes care of all the tinyurl problems?

Comment: I heard that URL-shortners, like goo.gl and bit.ly have usage limits.  You get 403 when you exceed that limit.  I heard it was something like 1 query per second or 1 million requests per day for goo.gl and 350 per hour on bit.ly.

One difference between the two requests is that urllib2 will do a GET and load the whole page, while httplib is only loading the HEAD, which includes the redirect.